# Gnuplot - plotting position(xyz) vs time data inside a specified space (eg a box) with a pause

Tags: 3d, plot, gnuplot

Can the following be done in gnuplot? If yes, how?

I have data for time vs position(x,y,z) in a table with  t,x,y,z as headers.

I would like to know if I can somehow plot the same time vs position of the particle inside a predefined space with a pause after each time step; so that i can see the evolution of the particles position with time. I would also like to know if I can draw a continuous line from the previous position to the current position so that I can actually see the track of its past.

Example data:

Lets say the predefined space is a box of 10x10x10 and my particle has the following positions over 3 seconds.

```
t x y z

0 1 2 3 

1 2 3 4

2 3 4 5

3 4 5 6
```

How do i see the tracking of the particle! my idea is that if i can pause the plot of every time step by a little bit, it will look like an animation which i can just capture using a screen capture software...

UNLESS, this data can be animated using gnuplot too

Is there any other software which does this more efficiently and/or elegantly if gnuplot is not the right tool!?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Create file `main.gp` and run `gnuplot main.gp` or `load "main.gp"` in gnuplot shell. Output is in point.gif.
Documentation
http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html
Also you can type `help` in gnuplot shell.

**main.gp**

```
set term gif animate delay 30 size 400, 400
set output "point.gif"
do for [n=1:4] {
    splot [0:7][0:7][0:7] "data" u 2:3:4 every :::::n w lp t sprintf("n=%i", n)
}
```

**data**

```
t x y z

0 1 2 3

1 2 3 4

2 3 4 5

3 4 5 6
```

[image]

EDIT: I switched to iterations as [@mgilson suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638636/gnuplot-plotting-positionxyz-vs-time-data-inside-a-specified-space-eg-a-box#comment15421794_11639174).

Comment: Thank You! That is what I was looking for.. Now if I wanted to add complexity to it and color the line by another quantity let's say pressure..  ? That would add another column P to the data and lets say it's from 1-10 and 10 being red and 1 being blue ...

Comment: i keep getting this error on first line.. i tried to look into the help files of set terminal and could not find anything wrong with it.. do you happen to know what the error in settings is for my computer? line1:invalid color spec, must be xrrggbb.. the little carat is on animate word. one thing i noticed is that when i type gnuplot, it says terminal typel is set to x11.

Comment: (+1) You and @andyras are trying to move in on my gnuplot question monopoly.  c'mon ... If I don't have that, where else will I get my rep ;^).  My one (legitimate) comment is that you could *probably* (?) do this using gnuplot's iteration which was introduced in gnuplot 4.3 without needing to rely on `reread` gymnastics (I don't miss those days).

Comment: @Suresh -- What is the first line of your plot script?

Comment: set term gif animate delay 30 size 400, 400

Comment: @Suresh What is your OS? What version of gnuplot you are using? For windows it is better to install the recent one http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot

Comment: I'm using RHEL 5 and gnu plot 4.0. Nothing else will install using yum..Tried it on windows with v 4.6 and the gif doesn't look the same .. The line is one full line and it does not change fr every n,. Looks like it only takes the last image

Comment: I updated main.gp. Now it should work with 4.6. I cannot say much about 4.0, it is very old.

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out..the code at every should be ::::n instead of the 5 colons. NOW, if i wanted to have 2 seperate files to be read and colored differently what would i do? i have this and it colors the 2 plots with red.. what if i wanted red and blue.?                          do for [n=1:46] {
   splot [0:0.002][0:0.0025][0:0.001] "data3.txt" u 2:3:4 every ::::n w lp t sprintf("n=%i", n)
    splot [0:0.002][0:0.0025][0:0.001] "data4.txt" u 2:3:4 every ::::n w lt 1 lw 1 pt 1 ps 1 lc rgb "blue" sprintf("n=%i", n)
} ### second splot throws an error.. and if same code is used for both splots-wont wrk